# What does the colon do in PATH

Tags: bash, terminal

I am new to bash, and I saw people often add `:` after a directory when modifying `PATH`. After searching for a while, I did not find an answer for that, or I believe I did not search it correctly. So I hope I could get an answer here.

Example:

```
/Users/chengluli/anaconda/bin:/Users/chengluli/.rbenv/shims:/
```

What does the `:` after `bin` and `shims` do?

Comment: I realise that my incomplete copy of PATH could be misleading to others, so I will paste a normal PATH here:

/Users/chengluli/anaconda/bin:/Users/chengluli/.rbenv/shims:/Users/chengluli/.rbenv/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Users/chengluli/.rvm/bin

Not sure if an editor could help me edit the question? Thanks!

Comment: Anybody can [edit], especially yourself, as the owner of the question. But I don't think it's a crucial thing to fix; this question is probably a duplicate anyway.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`:` is the separator. The `PATH` variable is itself a list of folders that are "walked" through when you run a command.

In this case, the folders on your `PATH` are:

- `/Users/chengluli/anaconda/bin`
- `/Users/chengluli/.rbenv/shims`
- `/`

Comment: Maybe also point out that `/` is a really insane thing to have on your `PATH`, whereas the example lacks a number of essential system directories like `/usr/bin`, `/usr/local/bin`, etc.

Comment: @tripleee, thanks! I am aware of that, it is my fault to copy a incomplete path as an example. I will modify that in the comment below my question.

Comment: can the path _start_ with `:`?  Just out of curiosity...

Answer (score 16):

As others have said, the `:` is a separator (Windows uses a semi-colon `;`).  But you are probably thinking of a trailing colon `:` at the *end* of the `PATH` variable.  For example:

```
/Users/chengluli/anaconda/bin:/Users/chengluli/.rbenv/shims:
```

From the bash man pages:

*A  zero-length (null) directory name in the value of PATH indicates the current directory.  A null directory name  may  appear  as  two  adjacent colons, or as an initial or trailing colon.*

Putting the current directory in the PATH is generally considered a security risk and a bad idea.  It is particularly dangerous when using the root user.

By the way, bash only uses $PATH on the first call of an external program, after that it uses a hash table. See `man bash` and the `hash` command

Answer (score 2):

If you run `ls -l 123` at the command line, you are telling bash to find the command called `ls` in the filesystem. However, `ls` is just a file name, bash needs the absolute path of `ls` in the filesystem. So bash searches for a file called `ls` in a list of default directories, one by one in order.

A list of default directories is stored in the `PATH` variable, separated by `:`.

Answer (score -1):

Th quotation from output of `man bash` command

> PATH
>   The  search  path  for commands.  It is a colon-separated list of directories in which the shell looks for commands (see COMMAND EXECUTION below).  A zero-length (null) directory
>                 name in the value of PATH indicates the current directory.  A null directory name may appear as two adjacent colons, or as an initial or trailing colon.  The default path is sys‐tem-dependent, and is set by the administrator who installs bash.  A common value is ``/usr/gnu/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/ucb:/bin:/usr/bin''.

If you have questions about bash script or environment variable, please use `man bash` firstly.